# Angularjs --can not selected any options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I use the

```
<select class="form-control" name="roleId" ng-model="addStaff.roleId" 
ng-options="ur.id as ur.name for ur in UserRole">
    <option value="">请选择</option>
</select>
```

the console display `angular.js:11598 TypeError: Cannot create property 'roleId' on boolean 'true'`.

If i use the ng-options the same error is displayed.

Comment: Is `addStaff` an object or a boolean?

Comment: it is an object  ; I also initialization the addStaff as “$scope.addStaff = {};$scope.addStaff.officeId="";$scope.addStaff.hrId="";$scope.addStaff.roleId="";”

Comment: `addstaff `should be an object first and `roleId` should be a property of that object.Can you show us `addStaff` object structure?

Comment: ok,got it, i set the addstaff is an boolean in the html .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialized the object in your angular controller as below.

```
$scope.addStaff = { roleId : {}};
```

May be there is possibility of roleId is already defined as boolean in your code. Try to make is as an object.

Comment: Thanks,i make a mistaks set the addStaff  as  an Boolean

Comment: Don't forget to Accept answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise object in controller

```
$scope.addStaff={};
```